# Commas in Python are moving my data in my CSV. How do I stop this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I'm loading a `.csv` from an Excel workbook and running some data cleaning on the file. However, the issue that I'm having is there are commas everywhere in the data, and this is moving my data around and breaking the schema. This is how I'm converting the df to a CSV (also not sure what `quotecar` is doing).

Does anyone know how to stop commas ANYWHERE in a dataframe from displacing columns?

```
gas_data.to_csv('Clean_zenos_data_' + datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m%d%Y%H%M%S''.csv'), index=False,
                quotechar="'")
```

[Here is a link to an example file with my displaced data, the name is causing the comma in this example but my true data set has allowed in all columns](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gl7g5XlYZGfRe0sjI7eFs7ucbZnXhr9K2lyn38DRmFM/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Save the file with different seperator

Comment: Have you got an example? Do i change my quotechar? or do i add a sep clause?

Comment: Have you tried quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC ?  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: @Mizanur yes just add `sep=';' ` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different delimiter, like a tab.

```
fname = 'Clean_zenos_data_' + datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m%d%Y%H%M%S')+'.tsv'
gas_data.to_csv(fname, index=False, sep='\t', quotechar="'")
```